# Does this store name and grade to an array correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

Does this store name and grade to an array correctly?

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Enter name and grade and save in an array
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] name = new String [50];
        int [] grade = new int[50];       

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter students name: ");
            String studentName = input.nextLine();

            name[i] = studentName;

            System.out.println("Enter students grade = ");
            int studentGrade = input.nextInt();

            grade [i] = studentGrade;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to test this program yourself...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  System.out.println("Enter students name: ");
  String studentName = input.nextLine();

  name[i] = studentName;

  System.out.println("Enter students grade = ");
  int studentGrade = input.nextInt();

  grade [i] = studentGrade;

  // Using print statements to check the values in your array...
  System.out.println("Name stored in name array is " + name[i]);
  System.out.println("Grade stored in grade array is " + grade[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Why can't you print the arrays after running this code to check if it's ok?

To print an array, lets say `arr`, just do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) //go over all i's from 0 to the array length
    system.out.print(arr[i]); // and print the value of the array in the i'th place each time
```

Comment: I am a rookie in programming nad just started working with arrays tonight. Havent learned yet how to print an array :-)

Comment: I wrote you how  to print an array.

Comment: Even simpler to print `arr` is `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))`

Comment: Thanks. Great help from all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, but you should better use a hashmap, because you want to store a name and the grade for this name.
These values in the arrays are not linked and, for example, you can't sort them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your data is stored correctly in the arrays. However, some notes to help you learn:

- If you're wondering what sort of data a variable contains, use print() or it's relatives to print it to the screen. This even works for arrays - you're not writing C!
- Using two arrays to store objects that should be paired will work, but is generally a bad idea. (What if you sort one and not the other? Now they're mismatched and unusable!)
- How are you planning to use the data? Just reading into a pair of arrays is... rather pointless.